# Role of basins of attraction in the Morse decomposition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, dynamical-systems, morse-theory

Let $M$ be a differentiable manifold and $F \in \mathcal{X}(M)$. We define a DS by
$$\dot{x}=F(x(t))$$

An ordered collection  $\mathcal{M}=\left\{M_{1}, \ldots, M_{l}\right\}$  of compact subsets  of  $S$ is called a Morse decomposition of $S$  if there exists an increasing sequence $\emptyset=A_{0} \subset A_{1} \subset \cdots \subset A_{l}=S$  of attractors in  $S$ called Morse filtration of $ \mathcal{M}$ , such that $$M_{k}=A_{k} \cap A_{k-1}^{*}, \quad 1 \leq k \leq l $$

Hence, we can generally define a pairwise disjoint decomposition of $S$ by
$$S= \dot{\bigcup}_{i<j=1}^N M_i \dot{\cup} C(M_i,M_j)$$
where $C(M_i,M_j)$ denotes the connecting orbits between the morse sets.

Lastly, we define the basin of attraction of an attractor as the largest open subset of $S$ such that $\omega(U)=A$, where $\omega$ denotes the limiting set.

---

**My question is the following:** What is the representation of the basin of attraction of an attractor in terms of morse sets?
Cann we define a similiar decomposition of $S$ (as above) in terms of basins of attraction?